# How do. I remove unwanted characters for column names in pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with some column names started with "USI_":
[image]

And I tried to use

df.rename(columns = {col: col.strip('USI_') for col in df.columns

but I got something different.

[image]

My expected output should be the columns like'DIVERSITY_QUESTION_RACE', 'DIVERSITY_QUESTION_GENDER','UNCOMMON_AFFILIATION'

How should I fix my code?
Thanks!

Comment: please post code/text, not images.

Comment: It is a large dataset and I cannot post all the info..

Comment: and indeed you shouldn't. but maybe try to break your problem down into pieces to get to its core. e.g. your df in principle looks like `df = pd.DataFrame({"prefix_A": [1, 2, 3], "prefix_B": [4, 5, 6]})` - you want to get rid of "prefix_" by renaming the columns (e.g. as `df.columns = df.columns.str.lstrip('prefix_')`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to take the column names of your dataframe as a list and do your string manipulation through the list and then assign those adjusted column names back to the dataframe

```
adj_col_names = []
for name in df.columns:
    adj_col_names.append(name.replace('USI_',''))

df.columns = adj_col_names
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using replace function

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('USI_','')
```

Comment: your initial answer with `lstrip` instead of `rstrip` would also do fine I think

Comment: Yeah exactly, Rstrip strip from the end of the string, Either way, you can avoid going into a loop like the first question by using obe of these functions.